# better way to jQuery set outerWidth(true) - width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

In short, is there a way to set the outerWidth?

```
$.outerWidth(true, newValue)
```

**Update:**
I found some addons that do this,
although I need one function definition not 3 addons to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var a = $('element');
    actualWidth = a.outerWidth(true),
    desiredWidth = 1000,
    difference = desiredWidth - actualWidth,

a.css('width',difference);
```

Answer (score 7):

You were pretty close. With jQuery 1.8+, just use:

```
.outerWidth(newValue, true);
```

Also works for:

- [`.innerWidth(val)`](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)
- [`.innerHeight(val)`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)
- [`.outerWidth(val [, true])`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)
- [`.outerHeight(val [, true])`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

*It actually became a setter with jQuery 1.8. That is 1 year after you posted your question. Moreover, it was listed in the [changelog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/), but nobody [updated the documentation](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/98) which explains that it might have been missed by many.*

If you have jQuery 1.7.2 or older, see [Xeo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6975851/1517690) (on this page) or use [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.8.4/#added-dimension-setters) 1.8.4+ which automatically enhances those methods into getters/setters (since in jQuery 1.8, those methods were actually [ported](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10877) from jquery-ui).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the width of an element, you can use these examples

```
var a = $("#element");

a.width(10);
a.css("width", "10px");
```

Comment: or for the fancy pants.. `a.animate({ width : "10px" });`

Comment: **Your answer is wrong** because it doesn't take paddings, borders and margins into account (which is what the _outer_ and `true` in the question mean). Sorry.